# Python - Create a group of lists using numbers

Tags: python, list, increment, decrement

say I have a string n = '22' and another number a = 4 so that n is a str and a is an int. I would like to create a group of lists like:

```
list1 = [22, 12, 2] #decreasing n by 10, the last item must be single digit, positive or 0
list2 = [22, 11, 0] #decreasing n by 11, last item must be single digit, positive or 0
list3 = [22, 21, 20] #decreasing n by 1, last item must have last digit 0
list4 = [22, 13] #decreasing n by 9, last item must be single digit. if last item is == a, remove from list
list5 = [22, 32] #increasing n by 10, last item must have first digit as a - 1
list6 = [22, 33] #increasing n by 11, last item must have first digit as a - 1
list7 = [22, 23] #increasing n by 1, last item must have last digit a - 1
list8 = [22, 31] #increasing n by 9, last item must have first digit a - 1
```

I am struggling on how to start this. Maybe you can give me an idea of how to approach this problem?

By the way if a condition cannot be satisfied, then only n will be on that list. say n = '20', a = 4:

```
list3 = [20]
```

Also this is for a school project, for indexes in a list which has list items. I can't think of a better way to approach the problem.

Comment: this made VERY little sense to me.. Try to rephrase your question, and be a little more clease please. Why do you want 8 lists? And what is the pattern in your list? And by the way, you can add a list to a list. [[1,2,3],[1,2,0]] is a perfecty valid list.

Comment: 1) `list3` doesn't match its description. 2) What if a condition can't be satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
def lbuild( start, inc, test ):
    rslt = [start]
    while not test(start,inc):
        start += inc
        rslt.append( start )
    return rslt

n = '22'
a = 4

nval = int(n)
print lbuild( nval, -10, lambda(x,y): (x<10 and x>=0) )
print lbuild( nval, 1, lambda(x,y): x%10 == a-1 )
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help. so i was able to do all the lists except for list4. i would like to create a list like [22, 13] - so it decrements by 9 but not if the last item is going to be equal to a or the modulus of the last item and 10 is equal to a.

Comment: Add inc as a parameter to test; you'll ignore it for the other lists, but can use it in list4 to "predict" the next value in the sequence.

Comment: so i've been working on this for almost a day, still no luck. i am going to use list4 to check for values of a list of lists in a diagonal way (using the items in list4 for index). so for example i have nval = '41', and a = 5 because i have a biglist which has list items and has 5 columns, 5 rows. i would like to check for the corresponding values of items at indexes biglist[4][1], biglist[3][2], biglist[2][3], biglist[1][4] - hence why i want to have a list like [41, 32, 23, 14]

Comment: @user1397215: "still no luck" regarding what?  Generating list4, or using it?  And if you want these to be lists of indices into a 2D array, wouldn't it make more sense for them to be pairs (i.e. (4,1) instead of 41)?